# Best Cache provider for Storm data

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, apache-storm

We are facing a load issue with Storm. We were using Storm state persistence for getting data from memory, to populate a real time report. But there were long GC pauses under heavy load environment.
Hence we created another service. Storm will be sending data to this service which maintains the in memory data structure. Although the long GC pauses have reduced, we are still not able to scale for a heavier load environment.
I tried using REDIS caching in the new service. But the write to REDIS under heavy load is very slow. May be due to its Single threaded model.

Can someone please suggest an effective caching mechanism for same. I checked Memcached but it has limitation on the size of value each key can hold.

Below are the code changes which I tried:

```
**Pom.xml**
<!-- Spring boot Redis dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

**Bean Configuration**
@Bean
RedisTemplate<String, List<Data>> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, List<Data>> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(new JedisConnectionFactory()());
} 

**RedisStore abstract class**
public abstract class RedisStore<T extends BaseEvent> implements EventStoreService<Integer, T>{
private ValueOperations<String, List<T>> valOperations;

final String type;  

public RedisStore(String type, RedisTemplate<String, List<T>> redisTemplate) {
    this.valOperations = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
    this.type = type;
}

public void put(Integer id, T elem) {
    List<T> existingElems = valOperations.get(getKey(id));
    if (null == existingElems) {
        existingElems = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    existingElems.add(elem);
    valOperations.set(getKey(id), existingElems);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you running Redis with managed Redis or single process?

Comment: Can you please add more info about the TP and latency?

Comment: I haven't modified anything in Redis Side. I am using Redis 3.2.5. Connecting to it using Spring boot project with JedisConnectionFactory.

Comment: @EshitaMathur What about the Redis cluster? You can also try other systems like IMDG or In memory db.

Comment: @sonus21 Will Redis cluster reduce latency?  Please suggest a in memory DB with better latency than Redis, which doesn't occupy current process heap space and can handle big data.

Comment: @EshitaMathur yes it can reduce when you have multiple queries in the pipeline for example if you have 3 nodes then 3 parallel queries can be made to Redis. Redis is a KV store, so very unlikely an RDBMS can beat the latency. But IMDG like Apache Ignite. The modern db by Aerospike is also promising, you can try and see which works better for you.